# Split matrices in a list with string criteria

Tags: r, list, matrix, split, unique

I created a list which contains 105 matrices as follows:

```
m<-vector("list",105)
for (i in 2:105) {
    m[[i-1]]<-Datos[(x[i-1]+1):x[i],1:14] }
m[[105]]<-Datos[(x[105]+1):533195,1:14]
```

For example a part of my matrix number 104 returns (In columns):

```
m[[104]]

    ID:                    
     8866 
     8866 
     8866 
     8866 
     8866 
     8866 
     8866 
     8866

  Date: 
     1990-4-15 
     1990-4-16
     1990-4-17
     1990-4-18
     1990-4-15
     1990-4-16
     1990-4-17
     1990-4-18

    Series: 
        APV 
        APV 
        APV 
        APV 
        INV 
        INV 
        INV 
        INV
```

These are some of my columns of the matrix. What I would like is to split this matrix using the series columns. I think it would be like a list of a list depending of the number of different Series there are. In this case there are 2: `APV and INV` ( Note that I don't know the names of the series for each matrix, so there must be a function that extract the unique different series)

In summary, I would like that:

```
m[[104]][[1]] returns:

        ID:                    
         8866 
         8866 
         8866 
         8866 


      Date: 
         1990-4-15 
         1990-4-16
         1990-4-17
         1990-4-18


        Series: 
            APV 
            APV 
            APV 
            APV 



And m[[104]][[2]] returns:

        ID:                    
         8866 
         8866 
         8866 
         8866 


      Date: 
         1990-4-15 
         1990-4-16
         1990-4-17
         1990-4-18


        Series: 

            INV 
            INV 
            INV 
            INV
```

Or maybe you come up with a more efficient way to do this.

PD: Didn't know how to put the columns at the same level

Comment: Can you format your question using `code` not italics. See other questions for examples

Comment: I tried editing, but do not understand how you can think that we will be able to help without seeing the output of `dput(head(Datos))`

Comment: There I tried to reformat the question. Hope you'll understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(plyr)
lapply(m, dlply, "Series")
```

or:

```
lapply(m , function(x)split(x, x$Series))
```

Comment: It tried with dlply but R works for too long and then I get a "no Response" from the software...... And lapply with split function says: "Error in split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) : 
  Lenght of group is 0 but lenght of data is > 0

Comment: Can you provide the ouptut of `class(m)` and `class(m[[1]])`? `str(m[[1]])` could also be useful.

Comment: Also, does every element of `m` have a `Series` column? You can check that by running `all(sapply(m, function(x) "Series" %in% colnames(x)))`.

Comment: I was writing wrong the header... it was "SERIE" not"Series"..... all(sapply(m, function(x) "Series" %in% colnames(x))) helped me a lot as returned false with "Series"...... Thanks flodel !